# Gem can't switch sources

Tags: macos, ruby, rubygems

[image]

What could be preventing me from switching gem sources?

Answer (score 1):

Are you in China?  If so, https://rubygems.org could be censored.

Try this source instead: https://gems.ruby-china.com